# define anonymous function using values from current scope?

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

I am trying to create an anonymous function but need to access variables from the current scope in it's definition:

```
class test {
    private $types = array('css' => array('folder' => 'css'));
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        //define our asset types
        foreach($this->types as $name => $attrs){
            $this->{$name} = function($file = ''){
                //this line is where is falls over!
                //undefined variable $attrs!
                return '<link href="'.$attrs['folder'].'/'.$file.'" />';                
            }
        }
    }
}

$assets = new test();
```

Obviously this example is very very minimalistic but it gets across what I am trying to do.
So, my question is,
How can I access the parent scope only for the definition of the function?
(once defined I obviously don't need that context when the function is called).

---

### Edit #1

Ok so after using [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372282/define-anonymous-function-using-values-from-current-scope#answer-11372286) I have added `use` as below; but now my issue is that when I call the function I get no output.

If i add a `die('called')` in the function then that is produced, but not if I echo or return something.

```
class test {
    private $types = array('css' => array('folder' => 'css'));
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        //define our asset types
        foreach($this->types as $name => $attrs){
            $this->{$name} = function($file = '') use ($attrs){
                //this line is where is falls over!
                //undefined variable $attrs!
                return '<link href="'.$attrs['folder'].'/'.$file.'" />';                
            }
        }
    }
    
    public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if (isset($this->$method) === true) {
        $func = $this->$method;
        //tried with and without "return"
        return $func($args);
    }
}
}

$assets = new test();
echo 'output: '.$assets->css('lol.css');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function($file = '') use ($attrs)
```

Comment: You want `return call_user_func_array($func, $args);` in `__call()`.